Training Samples Manager in ArcGIS Pro takes each polygon as a class
I am trying to  create segmentation on satellite image I have. I have something like 1000 polygons to use for training and I'm using the Classification Wizard. I have uploaded the sample polygons, but when I get to the Training Samples Manager, it seems like each polygon is a class, based on the FID field, while I have two classes for classification - one is text and one is code.
It's important to mention that my data has only one class.
My goal: to get my data with the right class and not with class per polygon
Here you can see my steps :

Select supervised method, classification schema and uplaoded my samples shapefile :


Segmentation - I use the default:




Training Samples Manager - I get accidently class per polygon, and I can't find where I can change it:


